# Spool query to file without output on screen

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Using `spool` on Oracle sqlplus correctly
sends the results of my queries to a file.

But I also see output on the screen.

Is it possible to see only the query without output on screen, and result on file? (This feature is the default on PostgreSQL psql client program).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SQL> SET TERMOUT OFF` command to get the result.

Here are some useful links collected from comments:

- [Oracle SqlPlus - saving output in a file but don't show on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813210/oracle-sqlplus-saving-output-in-a-file-but-dont-show-on-screen)
- [sqlplus, how to stop output to console](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2140535?tstart=0)
- [How to make sqlplus output appear in one line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/54149)
- [Remove blank lines from csv using shell script for oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35437443/440595)