# Spool query output to file (SQLPlus)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

This is not a duplicate of "[Spool query to file without output on screen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130380/spool-query-to-file-without-output-on-screen)"

Imagine I am spooling the below in a query:

```
SQL> select 'alter user '||USERNAME|| ' account lock password expire;' "Expiring Password" from dba_users where lower(username) in ('gunner','gunnersa','gunnerx3');

Expiring Password
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
alter user GUNNER account lock password expire;
```

Now I have spooled off the value and saved it to a file. I will be running it as a separate file for the expiring users. When I do that, I get some basic errors about the SQL command on the dynamic query.

Is there a way that we can get only the - `"alter user GUNNER account lock password expire;"` from the output from SQLPlus to a file?

I use Solaris (SunOS sintscdldmu004 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn that off, use [`set heading off`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG082)

It then should result in:

```
SQL> select 'alter user '||USERNAME|| ' account lock password expire;' "Expiring Password" from dba_users where lower(username) in ('gunner','gunnersa','gunnerx3');

alter user GUNNER account lock password expire;
```

You probably also want to use:

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TERM OFF
SET NEWPAGE 0
```

To get a "cleaner" SQL script when there are more than just three rows.